# Can you apply a shader to DOM elements?

Tags: html, opengl-es, webgl, fragment-shader

I am hoping to create a webpage that has a shader effect, covering all of the DOM elements. I know it is possible to apply shaders to a canvas, but I would rather not create my entire page inside of a canvas. Does anyone know a good way to accomplish this? I am assuming, if it is possible, it will involve some concoction of various technologies and frameworks.

Comment: It is not currently possible to render the browser's DOM elements in WebGL nor to apply shaders to DOM elements. The best you can do is like you said, render to a canvas either yourself or with a library. Of course you may run into issues. For example text input becomes problematic if you render it yourself because you'll have to manually support languages that use input method editors.

Comment: Alternative : Use css 3d transform func

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you seek for something like this [HTML GL](http://htmlgl.com/).

There is no easy way to "apply a shader" to the DOM... The DOM and WebGL are, natively, two entities that have nothing to say each other, two separated worlds, with their own logic, miraculousely joined together through the HTMLCanvasElement. The DOM is a very high-level abstraction layer, WebGL (thin abstraction layer over OpenGL) is a low-level abstraction layer.

This means that, except by using something like [HTML GL](http://htmlgl.com/), you have to implements yourself something to draw your DOM throught a canvas with WebGL...